# fetch data from weather api to model not work

Tags: json, flutter, fetch, weather

I have weather api url and I want to fetch data to model
and I make futurebuilder with future: weatherData().getData()

but nothing its appear and snapshop has no data !!

I want to fetch data from url and place in model
..

so can anyone help me with my problem or show me example of wright way of use url and model?

the fetch data class:

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:ramadi_daleel/weather/weather_model.dart';

class weatherData {
  Future<HomeCardModel> getData() async {
    var uriCall = Uri.parse(
        "https://api.weatherapi.com/v1/forecast.json?key=*******&q=ramadi,iq&days=3&lang=ar");
    var response = await http.get(uriCall);
    var bodyDecode = utf8.decode(response.bodyBytes);
    var body = jsonDecode(bodyDecode);
    return HomeCardModel.fromJson(body);
  }
}
```

the model class :

```
import 'dart:convert';

class HomeCardModel {
  final Location location;
  final Current current;
  final Forecast forecast;

  HomeCardModel({
    required this.location,
    required this.current,
    required this.forecast,
  });

  factory HomeCardModel.fromRawJson(String str) =>
      HomeCardModel.fromJson(json.decode(str));

  String toRawJson() => json.encode(toJson());

  factory HomeCardModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => HomeCardModel(
        location: Location.fromJson(json["location"]),
        current: Current.fromJson(json["current"]),
        forecast: Forecast.fromJson(json["forecast"]),
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "location": location.toJson(),
        "current": current.toJson(),
        "forecast": forecast.toJson(),
      };
}

class Current {
  final int lastUpdatedEpoch;
  final String lastUpdated;
  final int tempC;
  final double tempF;
  final int isDay;
  final Condition condition;
  final double windMph;
  final int windKph;
  final int windDegree;
  final WindDir windDir;
  final int pressureMb;
  final double pressureIn;
  final double precipMm;
  final int precipIn;
  final int humidity;
  final int cloud;
  final int feelslikeC;
  final double feelslikeF;
  final int visKm;
  final int visMiles;
  final int uv;
  final double gustMph;
  final double gustKph;

  Current({
    required this.lastUpdatedEpoch,
    required this.lastUpdated,
    required this.tempC,
    required this.tempF,
    required this.isDay,
    required this.condition,
    required this.windMph,
    required this.windKph,
    required this.windDegree,
    required this.windDir,
    required this.pressureMb,
    required this.pressureIn,
    required this.precipMm,
    required this.precipIn,
    required this.humidity,
    required this.cloud,
    required this.feelslikeC,
    required this.feelslikeF,
    required this.visKm,
    required this.visMiles,
    required this.uv,
    required this.gustMph,
    required this.gustKph,
  });

  factory Current.fromRawJson(String str) => Current.fromJson(json.decode(str));

  String toRawJson() => json.encode(toJson());

  factory Current.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Current(
        lastUpdatedEpoch: json["last_updated_epoch"],
        lastUpdated: json["last_updated"],
        tempC: json["temp_c"],
        tempF: json["temp_f"]?.toDouble(),
        isDay: json["is_day"],
        condition: Condition.fromJson(json["condition"]),
        windMph: json["wind_mph"]?.toDouble(),
        windKph: json["wind_kph"],
        windDegree: json["wind_degree"],
        windDir: windDirValues.map[json["wind_dir"]]!,
        pressureMb: json["pressure_mb"],
        pressureIn: json["pressure_in"]?.toDouble(),
        precipMm: json["precip_mm"]?.toDouble(),
        precipIn: json["precip_in"],
        humidity: json["humidity"],
        cloud: json["cloud"],
        feelslikeC: json["feelslike_c"],
        feelslikeF: json["feelslike_f"]?.toDouble(),
        visKm: json["vis_km"],
        visMiles: json["vis_miles"],
        uv: json["uv"],
        gustMph: json["gust_mph"]?.toDouble(),
        gustKph: json["gust_kph"]?.toDouble(),
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "last_updated_epoch": lastUpdatedEpoch,
        "last_updated": lastUpdated,
        "temp_c": tempC,
        "temp_f": tempF,
        "is_day": isDay,
        "condition": condition.toJson(),
        "wind_mph": windMph,
        "wind_kph": windKph,
        "wind_degree": windDegree,
        "wind_dir": windDirValues.reverse[windDir],
        "pressure_mb": pressureMb,
        "pressure_in": pressureIn,
        "precip_mm": precipMm,
        "precip_in": precipIn,
        "humidity": humidity,
        "cloud": cloud,
        "feelslike_c": feelslikeC,
        "feelslike_f": feelslikeF,
        "vis_km": visKm,
        "vis_miles": visMiles,
        "uv": uv,
        "gust_mph": gustMph,
        "gust_kph": gustKph,
      };
}

class Condition {
  final String text;
  final String icon;
  final int code;

  Condition({
    required this.text,
    required this.icon,
    required this.code,
  });

  factory Condition.fromRawJson(String str) =>
      Condition.fromJson(json.decode(str));

  String toRawJson() => json.encode(toJson());

  factory Condition.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Condition(
        text: json["text"],
        icon: json["icon"],
        code: json["code"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "text": text,
        "icon": icon,
        "code": code,
      };
}

enum WindDir { W, WNW }

final windDirValues = EnumValues({"W": WindDir.W, "WNW": WindDir.WNW});

class Forecast {
  final List<Forecastday> forecastday;

  Forecast({
    required this.forecastday,
  });

  factory Forecast.fromRawJson(String str) =>
      Forecast.fromJson(json.decode(str));

  String toRawJson() => json.encode(toJson());

  factory Forecast.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Forecast(
        forecastday: List<Forecastday>.from(
            json["forecastday"].map((x) => Forecastday.fromJson(x))),
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "forecastday": List<dynamic>.from(forecastday.map((x) => x.toJson())),
      };
}

class Forecastday {
  final DateTime date;
  final int dateEpoch;
  final Day day;
  final Astro astro;
  final List<Hour> hour;

  Forecastday({
    required this.date,
    required this.dateEpoch,
    required this.day,
    required this.astro,
    required this.hour,
  });

  factory Forecastday.fromRawJson(String str) =>
      Forecastday.fromJson(json.decode(str));

  String toRawJson() => json.encode(toJson());

  factory Forecastday.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Forecastday(
        date: DateTime.parse(json["date"]),
        dateEpoch: json["date_epoch"],
        day: Day.fromJson(json["day"]),
        astro: Astro.fromJson(json["astro"]),
        hour: List<Hour>.from(json["hour"].map((x) => Hour.fromJson(x))),
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "date":
            "${date.year.toString().padLeft(4, '0')}-${date.month.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}-${date.day.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}",
        "date_epoch": dateEpoch,
        "day": day.toJson(),
        "astro": astro.toJson(),
        "hour": List<dynamic>.from(hour.map((x) => x.toJson())),
      };
}

class Astro {
  final String sunrise;
  final String sunset;
  final String moonrise;
  final String moonset;
  final String moonPhase;
  final String moonIllumination;
  final int isMoonUp;
  final int isSunUp;

  Astro({
    required this.sunrise,
    required this.sunset,
    required this.moonrise,
    required this.moonset,
    required this.moonPhase,
    required this.moonIllumination,
    required this.isMoonUp,
    required this.isSunUp,
  });

  factory Astro.fromRawJson(String str) => Astro.fromJson(json.decode(str));

  String toRawJson() => json.encode(toJson());

  factory Astro.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Astro(
        sunrise: json["sunrise"],
        sunset: json["sunset"],
        moonrise: json["moonrise"],
        moonset: json["moonset"],
        moonPhase: json["moon_phase"],
        moonIllumination: json["moon_illumination"],
        isMoonUp: json["is_moon_up"],
        isSunUp: json["is_sun_up"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "sunrise": sunrise,
        "sunset": sunset,
        "moonrise": moonrise,
        "moonset": moonset,
        "moon_phase": moonPhase,
        "moon_illumination": moonIllumination,
        "is_moon_up": isMoonUp,
        "is_sun_up": isSunUp,
      };
}

class Day {
  final double maxtempC;
  final double maxtempF;
  final double mintempC;
  final double mintempF;
  final double avgtempC;
  final double avgtempF;
  final double maxwindMph;
  final int maxwindKph;
  final double totalprecipMm;
  final double totalprecipIn;
  final int totalsnowCm;
  final int avgvisKm;
  final int avgvisMiles;
  final int avghumidity;
  final int dailyWillItRain;
  final int dailyChanceOfRain;
  final int dailyWillItSnow;
  final int dailyChanceOfSnow;
  final Condition condition;
  final int uv;

  Day({
    required this.maxtempC,
    required this.maxtempF,
    required this.mintempC,
    required this.mintempF,
    required this.avgtempC,
    required this.avgtempF,
    required this.maxwindMph,
    required this.maxwindKph,
    required this.totalprecipMm,
    required this.totalprecipIn,
    required this.totalsnowCm,
    required this.avgvisKm,
    required this.avgvisMiles,
    required this.avghumidity,
    required this.dailyWillItRain,
    required this.dailyChanceOfRain,
    required this.dailyWillItSnow,
    required this.dailyChanceOfSnow,
    required this.condition,
    required this.uv,
  });

  factory Day.fromRawJson(String str) => Day.fromJson(json.decode(str));

  String toRawJson() => json.encode(toJson());

  factory Day.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Day(
        maxtempC: json["maxtemp_c"]?.toDouble(),
        maxtempF: json["maxtemp_f"]?.toDouble(),
        mintempC: json["mintemp_c"]?.toDouble(),
        mintempF: json["mintemp_f"]?.toDouble(),
        avgtempC: json["avgtemp_c"]?.toDouble(),
        avgtempF: json["avgtemp_f"]?.toDouble(),
        maxwindMph: json["maxwind_mph"]?.toDouble(),
        maxwindKph: json["maxwind_kph"],
        totalprecipMm: json["totalprecip_mm"]?.toDouble(),
        totalprecipIn: json["totalprecip_in"]?.toDouble(),
        totalsnowCm: json["totalsnow_cm"],
        avgvisKm: json["avgvis_km"],
        avgvisMiles: json["avgvis_miles"],
        avghumidity: json["avghumidity"],
        dailyWillItRain: json["daily_will_it_rain"],
        dailyChanceOfRain: json["daily_chance_of_rain"],
        dailyWillItSnow: json["daily_will_it_snow"],
        dailyChanceOfSnow: json["daily_chance_of_snow"],
        condition: Condition.fromJson(json["condition"]),
        uv: json["uv"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "maxtemp_c": maxtempC,
        "maxtemp_f": maxtempF,
        "mintemp_c": mintempC,
        "mintemp_f": mintempF,
        "avgtemp_c": avgtempC,
        "avgtemp_f": avgtempF,
        "maxwind_mph": maxwindMph,
        "maxwind_kph": maxwindKph,
        "totalprecip_mm": totalprecipMm,
        "totalprecip_in": totalprecipIn,
        "totalsnow_cm": totalsnowCm,
        "avgvis_km": avgvisKm,
        "avgvis_miles": avgvisMiles,
        "avghumidity": avghumidity,
        "daily_will_it_rain": dailyWillItRain,
        "daily_chance_of_rain": dailyChanceOfRain,
        "daily_will_it_snow": dailyWillItSnow,
        "daily_chance_of_snow": dailyChanceOfSnow,
        "condition": condition.toJson(),
        "uv": uv,
      };
}

class Hour {
  final int timeEpoch;
  final String time;
  final double tempC;
  final double tempF;
  final int isDay;
  final Condition condition;
  final double windMph;
  final double windKph;
  final int windDegree;
  final WindDir windDir;
  final int pressureMb;
  final double pressureIn;
  final double precipMm;
  final int precipIn;
  final int humidity;
  final int cloud;
  final double feelslikeC;
  final double feelslikeF;
  final double windchillC;
  final double windchillF;
  final double heatindexC;
  final double heatindexF;
  final double dewpointC;
  final double dewpointF;
  final int willItRain;
  final int chanceOfRain;
  final int willItSnow;
  final int chanceOfSnow;
  final int visKm;
  final int visMiles;
  final double gustMph;
  final double gustKph;
  final int uv;

  Hour({
    required this.timeEpoch,
    required this.time,
    required this.tempC,
    required this.tempF,
    required this.isDay,
    required this.condition,
    required this.windMph,
    required this.windKph,
    required this.windDegree,
    required this.windDir,
    required this.pressureMb,
    required this.pressureIn,
    required this.precipMm,
    required this.precipIn,
    required this.humidity,
    required this.cloud,
    required this.feelslikeC,
    required this.feelslikeF,
    required this.windchillC,
    required this.windchillF,
    required this.heatindexC,
    required this.heatindexF,
    required this.dewpointC,
    required this.dewpointF,
    required this.willItRain,
    required this.chanceOfRain,
    required this.willItSnow,
    required this.chanceOfSnow,
    required this.visKm,
    required this.visMiles,
    required this.gustMph,
    required this.gustKph,
    required this.uv,
  });

  factory Hour.fromRawJson(String str) => Hour.fromJson(json.decode(str));

  String toRawJson() => json.encode(toJson());

  factory Hour.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Hour(
        timeEpoch: json["time_epoch"],
        time: json["time"],
        tempC: json["temp_c"]?.toDouble(),
        tempF: json["temp_f"]?.toDouble(),
        isDay: json["is_day"],
        condition: Condition.fromJson(json["condition"]),
        windMph: json["wind_mph"]?.toDouble(),
        windKph: json["wind_kph"]?.toDouble(),
        windDegree: json["wind_degree"],
        windDir: windDirValues.map[json["wind_dir"]]!,
        pressureMb: json["pressure_mb"],
        pressureIn: json["pressure_in"]?.toDouble(),
        precipMm: json["precip_mm"]?.toDouble(),
        precipIn: json["precip_in"],
        humidity: json["humidity"],
        cloud: json["cloud"],
        feelslikeC: json["feelslike_c"]?.toDouble(),
        feelslikeF: json["feelslike_f"]?.toDouble(),
        windchillC: json["windchill_c"]?.toDouble(),
        windchillF: json["windchill_f"]?.toDouble(),
        heatindexC: json["heatindex_c"]?.toDouble(),
        heatindexF: json["heatindex_f"]?.toDouble(),
        dewpointC: json["dewpoint_c"]?.toDouble(),
        dewpointF: json["dewpoint_f"]?.toDouble(),
        willItRain: json["will_it_rain"],
        chanceOfRain: json["chance_of_rain"],
        willItSnow: json["will_it_snow"],
        chanceOfSnow: json["chance_of_snow"],
        visKm: json["vis_km"],
        visMiles: json["vis_miles"],
        gustMph: json["gust_mph"]?.toDouble(),
        gustKph: json["gust_kph"]?.toDouble(),
        uv: json["uv"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "time_epoch": timeEpoch,
        "time": time,
        "temp_c": tempC,
        "temp_f": tempF,
        "is_day": isDay,
        "condition": condition.toJson(),
        "wind_mph": windMph,
        "wind_kph": windKph,
        "wind_degree": windDegree,
        "wind_dir": windDirValues.reverse[windDir],
        "pressure_mb": pressureMb,
        "pressure_in": pressureIn,
        "precip_mm": precipMm,
        "precip_in": precipIn,
        "humidity": humidity,
        "cloud": cloud,
        "feelslike_c": feelslikeC,
        "feelslike_f": feelslikeF,
        "windchill_c": windchillC,
        "windchill_f": windchillF,
        "heatindex_c": heatindexC,
        "heatindex_f": heatindexF,
        "dewpoint_c": dewpointC,
        "dewpoint_f": dewpointF,
        "will_it_rain": willItRain,
        "chance_of_rain": chanceOfRain,
        "will_it_snow": willItSnow,
        "chance_of_snow": chanceOfSnow,
        "vis_km": visKm,
        "vis_miles": visMiles,
        "gust_mph": gustMph,
        "gust_kph": gustKph,
        "uv": uv,
      };
}

class Location {
  final String name;
  final String region;
  final String country;
  final double lat;
  final double lon;
  final String tzId;
  final int localtimeEpoch;
  final String localtime;

  Location({
    required this.name,
    required this.region,
    required this.country,
    required this.lat,
    required this.lon,
    required this.tzId,
    required this.localtimeEpoch,
    required this.localtime,
  });

  factory Location.fromRawJson(String str) =>
      Location.fromJson(json.decode(str));

  String toRawJson() => json.encode(toJson());

  factory Location.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Location(
        name: json["name"],
        region: json["region"],
        country: json["country"],
        lat: json["lat"]?.toDouble(),
        lon: json["lon"]?.toDouble(),
        tzId: json["tz_id"],
        localtimeEpoch: json["localtime_epoch"],
        localtime: json["localtime"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "name": name,
        "region": region,
        "country": country,
        "lat": lat,
        "lon": lon,
        "tz_id": tzId,
        "localtime_epoch": localtimeEpoch,
        "localtime": localtime,
      };
}

class EnumValues<T> {
  Map<String, T> map;
  late Map<T, String> reverseMap;

  EnumValues(this.map);

  Map<T, String> get reverse {
    reverseMap = map.map((k, v) => MapEntry(v, k));
    return reverseMap;
  }
}
```

Comment: getData() looks okay to me. Maybe edit the question with the widget code that tries to use it that doesn't work?

Comment: No need to decode response bytes, use response.body in jsonDecode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested your code. I figured out that your getData() function is working as expected. But, I found a few issues in your model class. There is some field that is setting dynamic numerical based on your API response. So, I used num type instead of int/double. I created a model class for you, and that is working seamlessly. I tested a few cases & it's working.

Here's the link for your model class: https://gist.github.com/dharambudh1/4d9daf1816dc6414ecc61ca817563078

Comment: Thank you so much for accepting/approving my answer. I'm glad it worked for you. Now, please consider upvoting my answer so this post may appear above other results & we both can have a good impression.